# Is every Lindelöf space Menger?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, lindelof-spaces

A space is [Lindelöf](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000018) if every open cover admits a countable subcover.

A space is [Menger](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000066) if given a countable sequence of open covers $\mathcal U_n$ for $n<\omega$ there exist finite subcollections $\mathcal F_n\subseteq\mathcal U_n$ such that $\bigcup\{\mathcal F_n:n<\omega\}$ is a cover.

Is every Lindelöf space Menger?

(The answer to this question is asserted in the comments of [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431292/is-there-any-example-of-a-lindel%c3%b6f-space-that-has-no-menger-dense-subspaces) - I'm posting here as I don't believe it's been answered on the StackExchange network directly.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the [Baire space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000028) $\omega^\omega$, the product of countably-many copies of $\omega$ with the discrete topology. This space is second-countable and therefore Lindelöf.

Let $\mathcal U_n=\{[t]:t\in\omega^{\leq n}\}$, where $[t]=\{f\in\omega^\omega:f\text{ extends }t\}$. Then given any choices $\mathcal F_n\subseteq\mathcal U_n$ for $n<\omega$, we will find $f\in\omega^\omega$ that's not covered. First pick $f(0)<\omega$ such that $[\langle f(0)\rangle]\not\in\mathcal F_0$. Then if $f(0),\dots,f(n)$ have been chosen such that $[\langle f(0),\dots,f(i)\rangle]\not\in\mathcal F_i$ for each $i\leq n$, we may also choose $f(n+1)<\omega$ such that $[\langle f(0),\dots,f(n),f(n+1)\rangle]\not\in\mathcal F_{n+1}$.

Now consider this $f$. If $f$ extended $t$ for some $[t]\in\mathcal F_n$, this would violate the choice made for $f(n)$. Thus $f\not\in [t]$ for every $[t]\in\mathcal F_n$, so $f$ is not covered. Thus the space is not Menger.